# javascript and html canvas animation image emitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hello I have been watching some tutorials on HTML canvas and animations and I wanted to create my own. I am having trouble though. :/ 
I am trying to create some clouds that start on the left side of the screen and move to the right side of the screen, and will eventually disappear when they get to a certain point. I don't have that code yet. I don't know how to handle transparency. But, that is not where my troubles lie.

Currently, my clouds do not move. I can generate 20 different clouds in different locations but they are failing to move. I have checked my code with other tutorials and I can not seem to find why it's not working. Maybe because I am using an image?? If I could find some help I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
$(function(){

    var leftcloudsrc = "ls/pics/cloud1.png";
    var rightcloudsrc = "ls/pics/cloud2.png";
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cloud');
    var cw = canvas.width;
    var ch = canvas.height;
    var cloudsArray = [];

    createclouds();

    function createclouds(){
    for (var i=0; i < 20; i++){
        var x = Math.random() * 150;
        var y = Math.random() * 300;
        var v = Math.random() * 4;
        cloudsArray.push(new Cloud(x, y, v));
    }
    animate();
    console.log(cloudsArray);
    }

    function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    for (var i = 0; i<cloudsArray.length; i++){
    cloudsArray[i].move();
    //new Cloud(x, y, v).create();
    }
    }
    function Cloud(x, y, v){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.v = v;
        this.create = function(){
        img = new Image,
        ctx = document.getElementById('cloud').getContext('2d');
        img.src = leftcloudsrc;
        var iw = img.naturalWidth;
        var ih = img.naturalHeight; 
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        }
        this.move = function(){
            this.x += this.v;
            this.create();
        }
    }
    // var cloud = new Cloud(0,0,0);
    // cloud.create();
});
```

i have tried writing to the console to make sure the information is saving and sticking, and yes, it is. i have even tried writing the .move() function to console to make sure the data changes, and it does. but it does not reflect visually???

Comment: Post any HTML you have also, use the code snippet tool and create a full working example for us to look at please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); // wrong
ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y); // right
```

You arent updating x and y. You are updating `this.x` and `this.y`

full code

```js
// test
    var leftcloudsrc = "http://www.freepngimg.com/download/cloud/10-cloud-png-image.png";
    var rightcloudsrc = "ls/pics/cloud2.png";
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cloud');
    
    // you dont have to define ctx again and again
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var cw = canvas.width;
    var ch = canvas.height;
    var cloudsArray = [];

    createclouds();

    function createclouds() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var x = Math.random() * 150;
            var y = Math.random() * 300;
            var v = Math.random() * 4;
            cloudsArray.push(new Cloud(x, y, v));
        }
        animate();
        console.log(cloudsArray);
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch)
        for (var i = 0; i < cloudsArray.length; i++) {
            var c = cloudsArray[i]
            c.move();
            // remove when crosses the canvas width
            if(c.x >= 500) {
              cloudsArray.splice(i, 1);
            }
            
            //new Cloud(x, y, v).create();
        }
    }

    function Cloud(x, y, v) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.v = v;
        this.create = function() {
            // invoke the constructor
            var img = new Image;

            img.src = leftcloudsrc;
            var iw = img.naturalWidth;
            var ih = img.naturalHeight;
            ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y);
        }
        this.move = function() {
            this.x += this.v;
            this.create();
        }
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="cloud" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: "img = new Image, // wrong, img = new Image() // right" This is not necessary with native objects such as Image. You can instantiate it (and any other native objects) without parenthesis.

Comment: i ddidnt know that

Comment: A `onload` handler for the image is also needed before drawing since setting src is a asynchronous operation meaning the image may not be loaded yet at the time drawImage is called (OP needs to incorporate a callback or promise mechanism for this to work properly, or at least a flag to check if the image has loaded).

Comment: i dont want do those as OP didnt do them